# Use PHP variable in SPARQL?

Tags: php, rdf, sparql

```
$abc=$_GET["q"];

$store = ARC2::getStore($arc_config);

         $p = '
           SELECT DISTINCT ?property WHERE { 
           ${"abc"} ?property ?object .
        }
    ';
```

I want to retrieve properties whose subject is equal to `$abc` (PHP variable) via GET method. But I am facing problems.
I am using ARC2 as RDFStore and SPARQL to retrieve and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Common string operations

For example

```
$p = sprintf('
       SELECT DISTINCT ?property WHERE { 
       %s ?property ?object .
    }
', $abc);
```

or

```
$p = "
       SELECT DISTINCT ?property WHERE { 
       $abc ?property ?object .
    }
";
```

or

```
$p = '
       SELECT DISTINCT ?property WHERE { 
       ' . $abc . ' ?property ?object .
    }
';
```

Comment: thanks a lot.     $p = sprintf('
                   SELECT DISTINCT ?property WHERE { 
                  <%s> ?property ?object .
                  }
                  ', $abc); did worked for me. thanks once again.